# Orace SQL - sorting with all upper case first

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

What if I wanted sorting to have all the upper case first then the lower case?

```
A
B
C
D
a
b
c
d
```

I tried searching the net and all I could find was sorting that would make it

```
a
A
b
B
c
C
```

etc..

but I wanted all upper case values sorted first then lower case ones.

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to conditionally order the column, based on upper or lower case. Then order by the original column.

```
select * from tablename
order by case when upper(col) = col then 1 else 2 end, col
```

Note: The ordering above works well when there is only one character in the string or the when the entire string is either upper case or lower case.

Answer (score 4):

Try to order by the `BINARY` value of your characters.

```
SELECT column 
FROM my_table 
ORDER BY NLSSORT(column, 'NLS_SORT = BINARY')
```